# Yesod - Error "couldn't match expected type" when extracting data from database

Tags: haskell, yesod

Having the following database models, I am trying to get the city name (a certain field from city - a related entity) of an event :

```
City json
    name Text
    countryId CountryId
    UniqueCity name
    deriving Eq
    deriving Show
Event
    title Text
    description Text
    date UTCTime
    cityId CityId

extractCityName :: EventId -> Text
extractCityName eventId = do
event <- runDB $ get404 eventId
    city <- runDB $ get404 (eventCityId event)
    x <- cityName city
    return cityName
```

And I am having this error even if the function is not called yet(at compile time):

```
Couldn't match expected type `HandlerT site0 IO t0' with actual type `Text'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: x <- cityName city
    In the expression:
      do { event <- runDB $ get404 eventId;
          city <- runDB $ get404 (eventCityId event);
          x <- cityName city;
          return cityName }
```

Can you please help me figure out what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

That's because the type signature of `runDB` is `YesodDB site a -> HandlerT site IO a`. Unless you want to run database related actions in yesod handers, you won't be needing `runDB`. The code for extracting city name would be like this:

```
extractCityName :: EventId -> ReaderT SqlBackend IO (Maybe Text)
extractCityName eventId = do
  event <- selectFirst [EventId ==. eventId] [LimitTo 1]
  case event of
    Nothing -> return Nothing
    Just event' -> do
               city <- getJust (eventCityId $ entityVal event')
               return $ Just $ cityName city
```

Now you can use the above function in the Yesod handlers when you actually need it. You can do the pattern matching in the result and send a `404` page if the result is `Nothing`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. Now the function compiles, but I still have an issue. As you said, the function can be used only in Yesod handlers. Do you know what can be done to make it work also in hamlet? I've posted another question with the detailed issue and code:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548361/yesod-function-call-in-hamlet-not-working